# Git - merge de develop a master

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-flow, gitlab-ci

Tengo un proyecto en local, que simplemente he iniciado git.

He estado trabajando en local en la rama **develop** y cuando he terminado el proyecto he hecho los siguientes comandos para moverme a la rama **master** y copiar el contenido de develop a master para ello he hecho

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

Ahora he decidido subir el proyecto a gitlab, y seguir el desarrollo desde allí para ello he creado una cuenta en gitlab y he puesto este comando para indicar el origen

```
$ git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/mi_usuario/proyecto_de_pruebas
```

Y luego he hecho un PUSH al servidor remoto con el comando

```
$ git push gitlab
```

Con esto lo que he visto que se me ha "pusheado" la rama develop, hasta aquí correcto.

Ahora mi pregunta es, el procedimiento para hacer los deploys de develop a master como deberia hacerlos?

Porque he probado en consola a hacer esto

```
drocha@dell-laptop /c/xampp/htdocs/proyecto_pruebas (master)
$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'

drocha@dell-laptop /c/xampp/htdocs/proyecto_pruebas (master)
$ git branch
  develop
* master

drocha@dell-laptop /c/xampp/htdocs/proyecto_pruebas (master)
$ git push gitlab
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream gitlab master


drocha@dell-laptop /c/xampp/htdocs/proyecto_pruebas (master)
$
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Lo que ha pasado es que habías subido la rama **develop** a remoto, pero **master** no existía en remoto. Por eso te ha pedido que la crees con ese `--set-upstream`. Ahora ya existe tanto master como develop en remoto.